# Sub-pattern globbing not working for lsearch

Tags: tcl, glob

I'm trying to use `lsearch` using glob test on sub-pattern, but it's not working:

```
set haystack {foo bar baz}
lsearch -inline -all $haystack baz; # finds baz
lsearch -inline -all $haystack *o; # finds foo
lsearch -inline -all $haystack {{baz,*o}}; # finds nothing
```

Sub-pattern works using the actual `glob` command (the files being the haystack in that case), so it appears to be an issue with `lsearch`.

```
glob {{b*,c*}}; # finds all files starting with either b or c
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the pattern that you use with `lsearch` is not meant to be able to match what you are trying to make it match. The [manual](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) specifies that it uses:

> the same rules as the [string match](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) command.

And there is no mention of the style `{ ... }`. If you look at the [manual for glob](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm) however, you will see the `{ ... }` syntax mentioned:

> {a,b,...}
>       Matches any of the sub-patterns a, b, etc.

You can however use `-regexp` if you know the syntax. For your example, you could use:

```
set haystack {foo bar baz}
lsearch -inline -all -regexp $haystack {baz|.*o}; # finds foo baz
```

Comment: `-glob` is not `glob`, got it. Planning to expose both `-regex` and `-glob` in the API so in the blob case guess I'll just go for a surrounding foreach loop and call it a day.

Comment: The multi-pattern stuff is built into the `glob` command. I sometimes wish it was directly in `string match` (or rather in the basic glob matcher engine that it uses)… but not enough to work on actually making it be so. It would be a reasonable area for someone to try their hand at writing a patch for (probably have to be a Tcl 9.0 feature) as it is mostly self-contained…